# Google Data Studio - How to get percentage of users who performed an event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

I have setup a dashboard where I could easily get the number of users who performed a certain event in a card. I have used the 'users' metric with a filter for the 'event category' and 'event action' and it gives me the number of users who performed this event.

What I really want to do is to display the percentage of the total users who performed the event. Instead of displaying 15 users performed the event I want to display 20% of users.

How can I achieve that? I cannot have a user metric filter and another without the filter to make the comparison. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I believe I've found a solution. I first tried your method, placing a filter on a widget to get the number of sessions in which a specific event has taken place. However, once you place a filter on a widget, it's impossible to pull in unfiltered metrics into that widget, such as the "total number of sessions."

To get around this, I created a goal. You can add one by either going to `Conversions>Goals` or `Admin>View[Desired Website View]>Goals`. Click on the "new goal" button, and then follow these steps:

1. In the goal setup menu, select the "Custom" preference and click "continue."
2. In the goal description menu, create a name, select type "Event" and click "continue" once more.
3. Lastly, in the goal details menu, fill in the require info for the event action/label that you want to track (NOTE: You need to assign a value to your event in order for this to work). The event I used has a value of 1 by default, so I set the value field to "Value - Equals to - 1". Click save, and you should be ready to go!

Once you set up your goal and start recording, `[your goal name](Goal # Conversion Rate)` will be an available metric in your dashboard. As I'm sure you've guessed, the conversion rate given is calculated as follows: Goal Conversion Rate = (Goal Completions/Total Sessions). Let me know if I can assist you further, but I think that will get you what you want.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem here is in how **Google** is firing goals vs. events. Events can happen an unlimited number of times during the session while a goal is fired only once.